# JAVA - Serial Data receiving illegal character

Tags: java, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to read a serial data with 4 characters sent from Arduino to the Raspberry Pi using the following codes.

```
int serialPort = Serial.serialOpen("/dev/ttyACM0",9600);
if(serialPort==-1){
    serialPort = Serial.serialOpen("/dev/ttyACM1",9600);
}    
char[] charArray = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}; //Initializing char array     
Serial.serialPuts(serialPort, 8 + "x"); //Sending Request Code to Arduino
int received = 0; 
while(received == 0){ //Wait for input
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        charArray[i] = (char)Serial.serialGetchar(serialPort);
        received = 1;
    }
}
String tempString = new String(charArray);
System.out.println(tempString);
```

However, upon reading the "tempString", it shows this ���� instead of the data sent by the Arduino.

The Arduino is sending the proper data so I don't think the problem is in Arduino. This code works with 1 character data. What do you think is wrong with these codes?

P.S. The codes work if executed in a loop, though the first execution outputs illegal characters

Answer (score 0):

The above issue may happen because of non-compatible character set.

If you are using pi4j for Serial Port Communication, then following method is deprecated.

```
Serial.serialGetchar(serialPort)
```

I suggest you using

`public static byte[] serialGetBytes(int fd,int length)`

then convert byte array into String using

```
public String(byte[] bytes,Charset charset)
```

I recommend using UTF 8.  you can try multiple character sets which suits your need.

[Please feel free to edit this answer to make it more useful]

Comment: I used both UTF-8 and ISO-8858-1 and both printed blank outputs. Do you know how can I solve this one or how can I know what charset to use? Thank you

Comment: Try US-ASCII.  Just a guess from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialCallResponseASCII

Comment: I tried US-ASCII and the output is still blank. Though this is not solving the problem I have, I just initially executed my code in the beginning of my project and discarded the output since only the first execution has illegal characters. The next executions or instances of the codes' output are all alright.